# Custom edit menu Angular Dashboard Framework

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dashboard

I'm working with Angular Dashboard Framework (sdorra) and I would like change edit menu;
[image]

At default click on menu I can add a widget, edit the dashboard, save and discard the changes as show below.

[image]

I would like add a new icon with a new function, in particolar case, i would like add a duplication function of the dashboard.

My html is the follow:

```
<div ng-app="isdashboard" ng-controller="dashboardController" 
                             ng-init="init('$name','$id', '$sid')" style="color:#A60076">
    <adf-dashboard name="dashboard" adf-model="dashboard.model" />
</div>
```

and my controller is

```
'use strict';
var model = {
    rows: [{
        columns: [{
            styleClass: 'col-md-4',
            widgets: []
        },{
            styleClass: 'col-md-8',
            widgets: []
        }]
    }]
};

angular.module('isdashboard', ['adf', 'adf.widget.clock'])
.config(function(dashboardProvider){
    dashboardProvider.structure('4-8', {
        rows: [{
            columns: [{
                styleClass: 'col-md-4',
                widgets: []
            }, {
                styleClass: 'col-md-8',
                widgets: []
            }]
        }]
    }),

    dashboardProvider.structure('6-6', {
        rows: [{
            columns: [{
                styleClass: 'col-md-6',
                widgets: []
            }, {
                styleClass: 'col-md-6',
                widgets: []
             }]
         }]
      })
   })
   .controller('dashboardController', function($scope, $http){

       $scope.init = function(name, id, sid){
          ....
   };

   $scope.dashboard = {
       model: model
   };
});
```

I know that there's a possibility to change menu like this example http://angular-dashboard-framework.github.io/angular-dashboard-framework/#/sample/03 , but i won't this solution.

Is it possible only add a item at default menu?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem, I mixed the solutions. 
First of all I created an `editTitletemplate` like the default:

```
<h1> {{model.title}}
<span style="font-size: 16px" class=pull-right>

<a href ng-if=editMode title="custom item" ng-click=callEvent('adfDashboardCustom')> 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat adf-flip"></i>
</a>

<a href ng-if=editMode title="add new widget" ng-click=addWidgetDialog()>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>
</a> 

<a href ng-if=editMode title="edit dashboard" ng-click=editDashboardDialog()>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
</a> 

<a href ng-if=options.editable title="{{editMode ? 'save changes' : 'enable edit mode'}}" ng-click=toggleEditMode()>
    <i class=glyphicon x-ng-class="{'glyphicon-edit' : !editMode, 'glyphicon-save' : editMode}"></i>
</a>

<a href ng-if=editMode title="undo changes" ng-click=cancelEditMode()>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat adf-flip"></i> 
</a>
```

At ng-click callEvent function is call. This function was added in the library:

```
$scope.callEvent = function(param){
    $rootScope.$broadcast(param, name, model);
};
```

The event is handled by dashboard like this:

```
$scope.$on('adfDashboardCustom', function (event, name, model) {
    //doSomething
}
```

I hope my efforts will be useful for someonelse.

Regards